# Hibernate Envers audit table foreign key columns gets null value from Element Collection - Spring Boot

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-envers

I have an entity with a Composite Primary Key implemented with @IdClass. When I want to use an Element Collection Table that uses primary key columns as foreign keys, hibernate envers gives null values to the audit table. When I disable auditing my code works fine. I could not understand what is the problem. Can someone help me?

My IdClass:

```
@Embeddable
public class SubtaskItemPK implements Serializable {
private UUID subtask;
private UUID item;

public SubtaskItemPK(){

}

public SubtaskItemPK(UUID subtask, UUID item) {
    this.subtask = subtask;
    this.item = item;
}

public UUID getSubtask() {
    return subtask;
}

public void setSubtask(UUID subtask) {
    this.subtask = subtask;
}

public UUID getItem() {
    return item;
}

public void setItem(UUID item) {
    this.item = item;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    SubtaskItemPK that = (SubtaskItemPK) o;
    return subtask.equals(that.subtask) &&
            item.equals(that.item);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(subtask, item);
}
}
```

My Entity that I want to use @ElementCollection:

```
@Entity
@Audited
@IdClass(SubtaskItemPK.class)
@Table(name = "subtask_items")
public class SubtaskItem {
private Subtask subtask;
private Item item;
private Collection<String> PhotoUrlList;

@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "subtask_id", referencedColumnName = "id", columnDefinition = "uuid")
public Subtask getSubtask() {
    return subtask;
}

public void setSubtask(Subtask subtask) {
    this.subtask = subtask;
}

@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "items_id", referencedColumnName = "id", columnDefinition = "uuid")
public Item getItem() {
    return item;
}

public void setItem(Item item) {
    this.item = item;
}

@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(
        name = "subtask_item_photos",
        joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "item_id", referencedColumnName = "items_id"),
                @JoinColumn(name = "subtask_id", referencedColumnName = "subtask_id")
        }
)
@Column(name = "url", columnDefinition = "TEXT")
public Collection<String> getPhotoUrlList() {
    return PhotoUrlList;
}

public void setPhotoUrlList(Collection<String> photoUrlList) {
    PhotoUrlList = photoUrlList;
}
}
```

[The ElementCollection table that I want to use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fB8uI.png)

The Error I am getting is:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:109)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:200)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3208)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3722)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:91)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478)
at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:348)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40)
at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:108)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1344)
... 155 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "item_id" violates not-null constraint
Detail: Failing row contains (null, null, dummyString, 1229, 0).
```

The query generated by hibernate is:

```
Hibernate: 
insert 
into
    audit.subtask_item_photos_aud
    (revtype, rev, item_id, subtask_id, url) 
values
    (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2020-04-08 13:15:12.050 TRACE [,0a5a8a68604ce2c0,4c33c3ce8b492db9,true] 17396 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [0]
2020-04-08 13:15:12.050 TRACE [,0a5a8a68604ce2c0,4c33c3ce8b492db9,true] 17396 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - [1230]
2020-04-08 13:15:12.050 TRACE [,0a5a8a68604ce2c0,4c33c3ce8b492db9,true] 17396 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3] as [OTHER] - [null]
2020-04-08 13:15:12.050 TRACE [,0a5a8a68604ce2c0,4c33c3ce8b492db9,true] 17396 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [4] as [OTHER] - [null]
2020-04-08 13:15:12.050 TRACE [,0a5a8a68604ce2c0,4c33c3ce8b492db9,true] 17396 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [5] as [VARCHAR] - [dummyString]
2020-04-08 13:15:12.095 ERROR [,0a5a8a68604ce2c0,4c33c3ce8b492db9,true] 17396 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: null value in column "item_id" violates not-null constraint
```

Comment: Is it possible in the audit table, you have the constrant of item_id not being null? Do you want to audit **after** the item id has been generated by the database? or do you want to allow null in the audit table?

Comment: @AkinOkegbile the columns "item_id" and "subtask_id" are part of the audit table's primary keys, so I don't want them to be null.

Comment: You don't want them to be null, THen don't pass them null? 

Why is the key needed on the audit table?

Comment: @AkinOkegbile Maybe I explained my question wrong but that is not the problem. Hibernate-envers documentation chapter 7: https://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/. Generated envers audit tables have original entity's (primary key + revisionNo) as primary key. Also, I am not passing them null hibernate-envers handles it wrong and passes them null. I have been using hibernate-envers for a while, but it is my first time using it with an element collection table with a composite primary key. Also my code works with examples with element collection wtih a single column primary key.

Comment: This looks like a bug with `@IdClass` handling in Envers.  Please open a jira issue.

Comment: <<spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.envers.store_data_at_delete = true>>

Does this one solve your question?